# Setting up bridges on Weblogic internal JMS in a clustered environment

Tags: queue, jms, weblogic, cluster-computing, weblogic12c

To give you guys a context, there are two servers (s1 and s2) in my cluster (c1). I have performed the following steps.

1. Created two JMS servers (jms1 and jms2), one for each server (s1 and s2).
2. Created a JMS module (m1) and set the entire cluster (c1) as it's target.
3. In the JMS module (m1), I created a uniform distributed queue (q1) with a subdeployment (subq1) and selected both JMS servers (s1 and s2) as the targets. I can see the two member destinations created for this queue. This queue is supposed to be my source queue. I want to read from this queue and send the messages to another application.

Now the confusion starts. I can't find anywhere in the Weblogic documentation on how to setup bridges for this queue. As a bridge would require a source bridge destination and a bridge destination asks for a connection URL. I have the following doubts with this field.

1. If this bridge destination is pointing to a distributed queue, why is it asking for a URL as that would need to point to a discrete endpoint. I understand that a bridge can be targeted to a cluster, should I leave the URL blank then?
2. Do I enter the URL for one of the servers in the cluster (maybe s1). And I setup another bridge destination for s2.
3. If the above is correct, what would I do if my target bridge destination is not distributed? Do I point both the bridges to the same target destination?

Thanks!

Comment: Which WebLogic Server version are you using ? JMS varies quite a lot between 10.3.x, 12.1.x, 12.2.x and 14.1.x

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin WebLogic version is 12.2.1.4. BTW query is resolved now :)

Comment: @siddhant Can you please add your resolution in the answers? BTW I am also trying to configure bridge between 2 JMS distributed queues. Want to know which url and port i need to use for bridge configuration.